# How to do a global validation in list editable django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to implement a swap feature over an integer field (sequence) in a list view (using editable) in Django admin site. My code:

**models.py**

```
class SortedMonitorables(models.Model):


    sequence = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    monitorable_id = models.CharField(max_length=80, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}-{}'.format(
             self.sequence, self.monitorable_id)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['sequence']
```

**forms.py**

```
class SortedMonitorablesAdminForm(ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = SortedMonitorables

    def clean_sequence(self):
        """Manually sequence validation."""
        try:
            sequence = self.cleaned_data['sequence']
            monitorable_id = self.instance.monitorable_id
            records = SortedMonitorables.objects.filter(sequence=sequence).\
                exclude(monitorable_id=monitorable_id).count()
            if records >= 1:
                raise ValidationError(
                    'Sequence {} is already defined'.format(sequence))
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise ValidationError(e)
        except Exception:
            raise ValidationError('Fatal error checking sequence')
        else:
            return sequence
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(SortedMonitorables)
class SortedMonitorableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = SortedMonitorablesAdminForm

    list_display = ('monitorable_id', 'sequence')
    list_display_links = ('monitorable_id',)
    list_editable = ('sequence',)
    search_fields = ['monitorable_id']
    list_per_page = 10

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        """Make some fields readonly on edition."""
        if obj:
            return self.readonly_fields + ('monitorable_id',)
        return self.readonly_fields

    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        """Setting form to use in formset."""
        return SortedMonitorablesAdminForm
```

In the admin site I have something like this:

```
monitorable_id    sequence

'aa'                | 1 |
'bb'                | 2 |
'cc'                | 3 |
```

In that list I can modify the sequence directly and the validation (unique value) that I have defined for the sequence field works good,  in both, the edit and list page. My problem come when an user wants to swap the sequence value in the list page, i.e: An user wants to change the sequence for 'aa' and 'bb' at the same time, getting something similar to:

```
monitorable_id    sequence

'aa'                | 2 |
'bb'                | 1 |
'cc'                | 3 |
```

When that scenario happens the user get an error since the unique sequence validation detects that both number were already defined/used by another monitorable. I want to get all the sequences values in that list editable (from the formset) before Django uses SortedMonitorablesAdminForm for validating every row in the list. How can I get those values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker has recommended me an application that just make what I need, so you can find it [here](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model)!. Using that application I did not need to validate the swap feature since in the template you could update only one row at the time.